# How to get id element in datatable

Tags: datatable

I using datatable plugin (datatables.net) with code below

How can i click anywhere in datatable to get image id

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><img id='1' href='#' src='Images/details_open.png'/></td>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td><td><img id='2' href='#' src='Images/details_open.png'/></td></td>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to resolve this problem :

I set hiden colum and use function :fnGetData to get id from this hiden row.